# How to draw a curved line in android?

Tags: android, canvas, line

I am new to Android and I am developing a sample project on drawing lines. I want to draw a curved or elevated line connecting two points `(x1,y1 and x2,y2)`. I tried `canvas.drawArc()` method, but the `RectF` values inside the `drawArc` method is just the x,y center points of circle. It is giving me an arc between my two points. But I want a curved line exactly connecting my two points. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is a simple example for drawing using canvas http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/01/10/draw-arcs-android-canvas/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare this method inside onDraw method:

```
private void drawOvalAndArrow(Canvas canvas){


    Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);

    float centerWidth = canvas.getWidth()/2; //get center x of display
    float centerHeight = canvas.getHeight()/2; //get center y of display
    float circleRadius = 20; //set radius 
    float circleDistance = 200; //set distance between both circles

    //draw circles
    canvas.drawCircle(centerWidth, centerHeight, circleRadius, circlePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerWidth+circleDistance, centerHeight, circleRadius, circlePaint);


    //to draw an arrow, just lines needed, so style is only STROKE
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);       
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);

    //create a path to draw on
    Path arrowPath = new Path();

    //create an invisible oval. the oval is for "behind the scenes" ,to set the path´
    //area. Imagine this is an egg behind your circles. the circles are in the middle of this egg
    final RectF arrowOval = new RectF();
    arrowOval.set(centerWidth, 
            centerHeight-80, 
            centerWidth + circleDistance, 
            centerHeight+80);

    //add the oval to path
    arrowPath.addArc(arrowOval,-180,180);

    //draw path on canvas
    canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, circlePaint);


    //draw arrowhead on path start
     arrowPath.moveTo(centerWidth,centerHeight ); //move to the center of first circle
     arrowPath.lineTo(centerWidth-circleRadius, centerHeight-circleRadius);//draw the first arrowhead line to the left
     arrowPath.moveTo(centerWidth,centerHeight );//move back to the center
     arrowPath.lineTo(centerWidth+circleRadius, centerHeight-circleRadius);//draw the next arrowhead line to the right

     //same as above on path end
     arrowPath.moveTo(centerWidth+circleDistance,centerHeight );
     arrowPath.lineTo((centerWidth+circleDistance)-circleRadius, centerHeight-circleRadius);
     arrowPath.moveTo(centerWidth+circleDistance,centerHeight );
     arrowPath.lineTo((centerWidth+circleDistance)+circleRadius, centerHeight-circleRadius);

     //draw the path
     canvas.drawPath(arrowPath,circlePaint);

}
```

Also this will find the two sides of the screen (Landscape mode) and will draw a perfect curve across the screen

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    PointF mPoint1 = new PointF(w/1.2F, h/1.2F);
    PointF mPoint2 = new PointF(w/24, h/1.2F);
    Path myPath1 = new Path();
    Paint paint  = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    myPath1 = drawCurve(canvas, paint, mPoint1, mPoint2);
    canvas.drawPath(myPath1, paint);

}

private Path drawCurve(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, PointF mPointa, PointF mPointb) {

    Path myPath = new Path();
    myPath.moveTo(63*w/64, h/10);
    myPath.quadTo(mPointa.x, mPointa.y, mPointb.x, mPointb.y);
    return myPath;  
}
```

Useful references on painting in android:

[How to draw Arcs in Android using canvas?](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/01/10/draw-arcs-android-canvas/)

[Basic Painting with Views](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Painting-with-Views)

Comment: Ya. Thank you buddy. But I already have seen this in a tutorial. I checked and changed some parameters in it. It worked

Comment: @Surendar can you give link of that tutorial??

Answer (score 9):

It might not be what u want, but take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html more precisely at moveTo, lineTo, quadTo and cubicTo. (The last 2 methods will draw bezier curves, either quadratic or cubic. If u don't know what those are, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve You only need to understand the parameters of the funcion, not the math behind it). For your purpose you can do like this:

```
Path mPath;
Paint paint;
mPath = new Path();
mPath.moveTo(x1, y1);
mPath.cubicTo(anchor1_x, anchor1_y, anchor2_x, anchor2_y, x2, y2); /*the anchors you want, the curve will tend to reach these anchor points; look at the wikipedia article to understand more */
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(width); //the width you want 
canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
```