# how to draw a curved line with my finger?

Tags: android

I want to draw curved line in android studio without ArrayList.
I know how to draw with Arraylist, but I just want to know without Arraylist.

Anyhow, I want to draw curved line a set length without use Arraylist. How can I do this?
Here is my code but it doesn't work well.

```
package com.example.final_practice3;

import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));
}

private class MyView extends View {
    private int count = 0;
    private int[][] points = new int[500][2]; //point x, y in array to 500size


    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //first point
                points[0][0] = (int) getX();
                points[0][1] = (int) getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //When finger is moving, save to points array
                for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++) {
                    points[i][0] = (int) event.getX();
                    points[i][1] = (int) event.getY();
                    count++;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //When finger is up, draw the curved line
                this.invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        //draw curved line with points array
        for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(points[i - 1][0], points[i - 1][1], points[i][0],points[i][1],paint);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a curved line in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704200/how-to-draw-a-curved-line-in-android)

Comment: thanks for ur comment, but that posting is about drawing a curve at a given coordinates. and I want to draw a curve along my finger.